# Solve $z^2 + \bar{z} = \frac 1 2$, for $z \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to solve the equation following in a set of complex numbers:

$$z^2 + \bar z = \frac 1 2$$

**My work so far**

Apparently I have a problem with transforming equation above into form that will be easy to solve. I tried to multiply sides by $z$ and use fact that: $z\bar z = |z|^2$ but it doesn't seem great idea. After that I tried the following:

$$\bar z = \frac 1 2 - z^2 \Leftrightarrow |z| = | \frac 1 2 - z^2|$$

and then rewrite as $z = Re(z) +Im(z)$ but also result was not satisfying. Could you please give me a hand with solving this equation?

Comment: $\bar z = \frac 1 2 - z^2 $ implies $|z| = | \frac 1 2 - z^2|$, but is not equivalent.

Comment: Did you try to set $z=a+bi$ and solve the resulting system for $a,b$?

Comment: Please don't use math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Answer (score 5):

Write $z=x+iy$, so $z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$. So, equating real and imaginary parts,
$$
x^2-y^2+x=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
2xy-y=0
$$
So this means that $y=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Can you see where to go from there?

Answer (score 3):

Taking conjugates $\,z^2 + \bar z = \frac 1 2 = \bar z ^2 + z\,$, then eliminating $\bar z = \frac{1}{2}-z^2$ between the two:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{2}-z^2\right)^2+z &= \frac{1}{2}
\\ \iff\;\;\;\; (2z^2-1)^2+4z&=2
\\ \iff\;\;\;\; 4z^4-4z^2+4z-1&=0
\\ \iff\;\;\;\; 4z^4-(2z-1)^2&=0
\\ \iff\;\;\;\; \left(2z^2-2z+1\right)\left(2z^2+2z-1\right)&=0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$z^2 + \bar{z} = \frac 1 2 \iff \bar z^2 + z = \frac 1 2$$

and then subtracting we obtain

$$z^2-\bar z^2 +\bar z-z=0 \iff (z-\bar z)(z+\bar z-1)=0$$

that is

$$z=\bar z \quad \lor \quad z+\bar z=1$$

And it is easy conclude form here by substitution in the original equation and solving the quadratics

- $z^2+z=\frac12$
- $z^2+1-z=\frac12$

Answer (score 1):

We  may also  solve the equation using the "polar form", $ \ z \ = \ r·[ \ \cos \theta  + i·\sin \theta \ ] \ \ : $
$$  z^2 \ + \ \overline{z} \ \  = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ r^2·[ \ \cos (2 \theta) \ + \ i·\sin (2 \theta) \ ] \ + \ r·[ \ \cos \theta \ - \ i·\sin \theta \ ] \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ . $$

First, equating the imaginary parts produces $ \ r^2·\sin (2 \theta) \ - \ r· \sin \theta   \ = \ 0 \ \ . \  $  Since $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ $ does not satisfy the original equation, we have $ \ r \ \neq \ 0 \ $ and can factor this trigonometric equation as $ \ \sin \theta · ( 2r·\cos \theta - 1) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ giving us $ \ \sin \theta \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ \pi \ \ \ $ or $ \ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{1}{2r} \ \ . \ $

Equation of the real parts leads to $ \ r^2·\cos (2 \theta) \ + \ r· \cos \theta   \ = \ \frac12 \ \ . \  $  In the first case, we find

$ \mathbf{\theta \ = \ 0 \ \ : } \quad \quad r^2·1 \ + \ r·1 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ = \ \frac{-1 \ \pm \ \sqrt3}{2} \ \ ; \ $

$ \mathbf{\theta \ = \ \pi \ \ : } \quad \quad r^2·1 \ + \ r·(-1) \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ = \ \frac{1 \ \pm \ \sqrt3 }{2} \ \ . $

If we allow the interpretation of a point with "negative radius" in direction $ \ \Theta \ $ as the point in direction $ \ -\Theta \ $ with the absolute-value of that radius, then this case provides (redundantly) the two real roots of the original equation $$ \left( \ \frac{  \sqrt3 \ - \ 1}{2} \ , \ 0 \ \right) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \boxed{ \ z \ \ = \ \ \frac{  \sqrt3 \ - \ 1}{2} \ } \ \ , \ \ \left( \ \frac{  \sqrt3 \ + \ 1}{2} \ , \ \pi \ \right) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \boxed{ \ z \ \ = \ \ -\frac{  \sqrt3 \ + \ 1}{2} \ } \ \ . $$

[We can check that $ \ z^2 \ = \  \left( \frac{  \pm \sqrt3 \ - \ 1}{2} \right)^2 \ = \  \frac{ 4 \ \mp \ 2 \sqrt3 }{4} \ = \ 1 \ \mp \frac{  \sqrt3 }{2} $ and $ \ \overline{z} \ = \ z \ = \ \frac{  \pm \sqrt3 \ - \ 1}{2} \ \ , \ $ so their sum is $ \ \frac12 \ \ . \ ] $

For the second case, the real-parts equation gives us
$$   r^2·\cos (2 \theta) \ + \ r· \cos \theta \ \ = \ \ r^2·( \ 2 \cos^2 \theta \ - \ 1 \ ) \ + \ r· \cos \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac12  $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ r^2·\left( \ 2· \left[ \frac{1}{2r} \right]^2 \ - \ 1 \ \right) \ + \ r· \frac{1}{2r} \ \ = \ \  \frac{1}{2}  \ - \ r^2  \ + \ \frac12 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac12 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{1}{2 \ · \ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}} \ = \ \pm \frac{\sqrt2}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \theta \ \ = \ \ \pm \frac{\pi}{4} \ \ , \ \ \pm \frac{3 \pi}{4} \ \ . $$

We obtain four complex roots, $ \ \pm \frac12 \ \pm i·\frac12 \ \   $ (again considering negative radii).  But since $ \ z^2 \ = \ \frac14 - \frac14 \pm i·\frac12 \ = \ \pm i·\frac12 \ \ $ and $ \ \overline{z} \ = \ \pm \frac12 \ \mp i·\frac12 \ \ , \ $ we see that the roots with negative real part are "spurious".  Thus, the two complex-conjugate roots of the original equation are $ \ \boxed{ \ z \ = \ \frac12 \ \pm \ i·\frac12 \ } \ \ . $